# Identify features result panel missing

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I'm using QGIS 3.14 on Windows 10.   When I try to use the 'identify features' tool, it clearly highlights the item I'm looking to identify, but no results panel appears.  There is nothing docked and it doesn't seem to matter what item or layer I try to identify, nothing shows up.  I've closed all other windows and tried restarting QGIS, but nothing appears.

Comment: Do/Did you use multiple screen?

Answer (score 1):

Actually just found it was hidden with my layer styling panel, just couldn't see it for some reason.  I closed my layer styling panel, and it appeared.

Comment: Well done on solving the issue.  Please [edit] this answer to include a bit more detail just where/how you found it (in case future users have the same issue), and remember to mark this as the answer.